# how many item render instances will be created for flex data Grid

Tags: apache-flex

How many item render instances will be created for a flex data Grid , which has 200 rows of data and only 50 are visible at one shot. To see next 50 you need to scroll . Can someone give an explanation of the number as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex DataGroups use *virtualization*, meaning only visible items are rendered.

Per [Flex 4: Understanding DataGroups and VirtualLayouts](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2010/08/02/flex-4-understanding-datagroups-and-virtuallayouts/)

> DataGroups allow you to do something called Virtualization. What that
>   means is, if you have an ArrayCollection with lets say 50 items in it
>   and your DataGroup is only showing 10 items at a time, then Flash
>   Player will only render 10 visual elements on the screen and as you
>   keep scrolling up or down, those renderers will be recycled within
>   each other. In other words, there will only ever be a few visual
>   renderers created based on the size of your visible component.